# angularjs new services won't work

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs project with 6 services. Everyone of them works fine, but now if i create a new service and try to inject it, it fails. I tried to inject the same service in another project and it works.

Here is the service:
**app-services/test.service.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('TestService', TestService);

    TestService.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function TestService($scope) {
        var service = {};
        service.Test = Test;
        return service;
        function Test() {
            //Stuff
        }
    }
})();
```

Here is the controller in which i try to inject it: **app-index/functions/functions.controller.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('FunctionController', FunctionController);

    FunctionController.$inject = ['$scope',  'FlashService', '$location', 'UploaderService', '$q','TestService'];
    function FunctionController($scope, FlashService, $location, UploaderService, $q, TestService) {
        var vm = this;
        var fileContainers;

        $scope.UploadFile = UploadFile;

        function UploadFile() {
            TestService.Test();
        }      
    }
})();
```

In the **index.html**

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="app-services/test.service.js"></script>
<script src="app-index/functions/functions.controller.js"></script>
```

**Error**

```
HTML1300: Navegación realizada.
localhost:44373
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.0/$injector/unpr?
p0=TestServiceProvider%20%3C-%20TestService%20%3C-%20FunctionController
at Anonymous function 
(https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js:44:389)
at d (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js:42:60)
at Anonymous function 
(https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js:44:449)
at d (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js:42:60)
at e (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js:42:298)
at instantiate (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js:43:242)
at Anonymous function 
(https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js:93:137)
at link (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular-route.min.js:7:316)
at Anonymous function 
(https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js:16:45)
at ta (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js:84:35) <div 
class="ng-scope" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" ng-view="">
```

As i said, the other services injected in the controller are working. And I don't think the problem is in TestService since it is working on another project.

I'm developing in Visual Studio

Edit: I removed $scope from service, but it still doesn't work

Edit 2: It looks like the problem is the caching. It loads the old version of index.html that hasn't got the reference of the new service..

Comment: Problem with your TestService. You are not able to inject $scope to 'factory' or 'service'

Comment: I removed the $scope from the service but nothing changed

Comment: try loading the **app.js** last in the scripts section of your html

Comment: I would try 2 things: 
1) in the chrome dev tools (assuming you are using chrome) go into the sources panel and click on 'pause on exceptions' (the octagon with a pause icon inside) to see if you can get more context regarding the error. I would also 
2) load an un-minified version of angular to try to grok what's going on when angular error's out.